# Hashing passwords on client side before sending to server in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, https, laravel-5.1

Greeting of the evening :)

I am working on an application on https where user  fill login form and submit then one array send to server but security auditor said hacker can see password in plain text to give check as control. I tried but application gone down. **there is any  way solve it?**﻿

Comment: StackOverflow is for asking about _a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development_. Your question doesn't qualify as any of those and is pretty ambiguous. It's not even clear what you're actually asking for help with.

Comment: Hello @Sherif ! You are right but I am asking for the algorithm in laravel to solve or prevent my application from unauthorized access. My question is clear. SSL is the solution for my question as said Labradorcode.

Comment: First, there is no algorithm to solve or prevent unauthorized access. A question of "_how do I prevent unauthorized access_" by itself is too broad, because there are too many possible answers or good answers would be too long for this format. Second, if your real question is specifically "_how do I prevent a man in the middle attack_" then it's not  a programming question for StackOverflow. It belongs on [security.stackexchange.com where there is already an answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/preventing-a-spoofing-man-in-the-middle-attack).

Comment: I have found a less solution http://laravel.io/forum/07-25-2016-hashing-passwords-on-client-side-before-sending

Comment: @CodeLove, using an encrypted connection is vital. Without that you have no security between the browser and the server. Client-side hashing adds no security at all. (If an attacker intercepts the hashed password he can later send that same hash himself. The hash effectively becomes a new plaintext.)

Answer (score 1):

If communication between client <-> server is over HTTPS, hacker don't have possibility to see what client send to server. Only if hacker use Man-in-the-middle attack.

If you hash password on client site hacker can decode this hash because he know how password is hashed.